# Solucion para error de base de datos 42000 con relacion ono a uno en django

Tags: django

Hola espero que me puedan ayudar en este inconveniente
Estoy haciendo unas practicas y tengo que hacer un seguimiento de un formulario que esta dividido en nombre de etapas, nombre del procesos, acciones del proceso, detalles del los proceso y todo eso llena un campo, en total son 183 campos que el usuario debe llenar y todos esos 183 campos generan un reporte .

estoy trabajando con sql server 2019 y django.

**MODELOS DE BASE DE DATOS**

```
class Parametro(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='TIPO', blank=False)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='NOMBRE', blank=False)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='FECHA DE 
            REGISTRO DEL PARAMETRO', blank=False)
    valor_ordenamiento = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='NUMERACION 
            POR TIPO DE PARAMETRO',blank=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='CODIGO DE BUSQUEDA RAPIDA', 
            blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        param = "{0} {1}"
        return param.format(self.tipo, self.nombre)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Parametro - Admin'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Parametros -Admin'
        db_table = 'Parametro'


class Constructor(models.Model):
    ordenamiento = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='ORDENAMIENTO DE 
    REGISTRO', blank=False, null=False)
    etapa_id = models.ForeignKey(Parametro, related_name='ETAPA', 
            on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    proceso_id = models.ForeignKey(Parametro, related_name='PROCESO', 
            on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    campo_id = models.ForeignKey(Parametro, related_name='CAMPO', 
            on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    detalle_id = models.ForeignKey(Parametro, related_name='DETALLE', 
            on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        cons = self.id, self.ordenamiento, self.etapa_id.nombre + self.proceso_id.nombre 
            + self.campo_id.nombre + self.detalle_id.nombre
        return cons

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estructura Reporte Compras  - Admin'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estructura Reportes  - Admin'
        db_table = 'Estructura'


class Reporte(models.Model):

    def validar_edicion(self):
        pass

    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='CREADOR REPORTE',blank=True)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='FECHA DE 
            CREACION DEL REPORTE', blank=True)
    campo1 = models.OneToOneField(Constructor, verbose_name='SELECCIONE EL CAMPO DEL 
            REPORTE A INGRESAR CON EL RESPECTIVO ORDENAMIENTO', on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
            related_name='rcampo1', validators=[validar_edicion], blank=True)
    valor1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='INGRESE EL REGISTRO 
            SOLICITADO',blank=True)
    observacion = models.TextField(verbose_name='OBSERVACIÓN FINAL DE REPORTE', 
            blank=True)
    fecha_finalizacion = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Fecha de 
            finalización del reporte', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        text = self.usuario + self.observacion
        return text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reporte - Compras Publicas'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reportes'
        db_table = 'Reporte'
```

> NOTA: No le presten atención a los `__str__` ya que la presentación
> los estoy armando en models. Admin

En este modelo Reporte creo todos los registro  solo puse un ejemplo de un campo y un registro a solicitar que ingrese, pero los campos tienen que ser llamados con relación uno a uno, ya que solo quiero que se puedan insertar en el campo una sola vez, es decir una estructura de campo en la tabla Estructura pertenece solo a un campo en Reporte.
De esos campos y valor son 183.
Son 183 registros que el usuario tiene que llenar en el formulario de reporte y 183 campos que llamo con relacion uno a uno a la tabla estructura.
En la tabla estructura el admin arma el formulario que desea deacuerdo a las necesidades con una relacion uno a muchos

**ERROR**
El código como tal está todo bien, pero al momento que en el Admin entro a reporte me sale un error de base de datos el cual es el siguiente

[image: error 42000 sql server]

según leí ese error es que ha explotado la capacidad de datos en el administrador de Django o en la base de datos no tengo idea  talvez creo que un problema de la relación de los 183 campos en reporte aunque cada campo tiene un related_name='' para diferenciar lógicamente